# php preg_match_all and preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace, preg-match-all

i want to encode all input values to base64 encoded. So i need some help... My code is:

```
$check_hash = preg_match_all('/<input type="text" value="(.*?)">/mis', $ays, $hashtweet);

$ays = preg_replace('/<input type="text" value="(.*?)">/', base64_encode($hashtweet[1]), $ays);

echo $ays;
```

And my page is here:
http://www.ceay.biz/test/vkmp3/

But it dont gives me what i want. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what do you expect as a correct value?

Comment: I am stupid :) I just only change all input values to encoded one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preg_replace_callback to do this (requires php 5.3 for closure)

```
$ays = preg_replace_callback('/value="(.*)"/', function ($match) {
                          return "value=\"".base64_encode($match[1])."\""; }, $ays);
```

for pre php 5.3 environments

```
if (!function_exists("valueReplacer")){
    function valueReplacer ($m){
        return "value=\"".base64_encode($m[1])."\""; 
    }
}
$ays = preg_replace_callback('/value="(.*)"/', "valueReplacer", $ays);
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in index.php on line 65

Comment: closure syntax only works for php 5.3+ ... I will update showing non-closure usage

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call [**preg_replace_callback**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) in order to execute PHP code as replacement:

```
$ays = preg_replace_callback('/<input type="text" value="(.*?)">/', function ($m) {
                             return base64_encode($hashtweet[1]); }, $ays);
```

Comment: Yes pls provide sample values for `$hashtweet` and `$ays`

Comment: If you can provide provide sample values for `$hashtweet` and `$ays` it will be very helpful.

Comment: hashtweet is a array. Here is the hashtweet array
http://www.ceay.biz/test/vkmp3/

Comment: Do you want to base64_encode all the elements in the `$hashtweet` array? Honestly I couldn't understand your problem fully.

Comment: yes i want to base64_encode all the elements in the $hashtweet array

Comment: In that case you can just run a for-each loop using above preg_replace_callback call.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

```
$string = '<input type="text" value="http://cs9-10v4.vk.me/p1/63ec3a36b2eb1c.mp3">';
preg_match('/<input type="text" value="(.*)">/', $string, $matches);
$string = preg_replace('/(<input type="text" value=").*(">)/', "$1".base64_encode($matches[1])."$2", $string);
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: ok, then you need to do a foreach over all values that you have. How you are get the inputs?